# Preg_replace change chars

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a problem with the function preg_replace.

How replace chars `[` to `&1;` and `]` to `&2;`

When first is tag `[cd]` and last tag is `[/cd]`?

input:

```
[cd]H[o]m[/cd]
```

output:

```
[cd]H&1;o&2;[/cd]
```

I tried:

```
preg_replace('#\[cd\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/cd\]#i', '[cd]\1[/cd]', '[cd]H[o]m[/cd]');
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you don't show what you have already tried (even if it is wrong), your question will be closed as *off-topic* or *too broad*. Add your attempts to the question.

Comment: Okej, thanks for information, i added.

Comment: can string contain more than one group as `[o]` ? For example, [cd]H[o]m[i]jsd[/cd]

Comment: Yes, I want to make all the characters were swapped from [ and ]

Comment: What if `[cd]` tags are nested: `[cd]H[o]m[cd]P[o]m[/cd]jk[/cd]`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make changes to a captured string, you can use `preg_replace_callback()`. This calls a function instead of using a simple string as the replacement.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('#\[cd\]([\s\S]*?)\[/cd\]#i', function($matches) {
    $str = str_replace(array('[', ']'), array('&1', '&2'), $matches[1]);
    return "[cd]{$str}[/cd]";
}, '[cd]H[o]m[/cd]');
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `/` in the regexp if you're using a different character as the delimiter -- that's the reason you used `#` as the delimiter.

Comment: @splash58 Thanks. It's parsing `[/cd]` as a subscript.

Comment: @splash58 - error because " " is not valid, use:
return '[cd]'.$str.'[/cd]';

Comment: @Xeer Adding the `{}` around the variable fixed the problem.